# Includes with Chained Where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having a strange issue. I would like to chain a few where clauses in my controller after a call to includes, but it's only working when it's not chained. Here's the code that doesn't work (what I would like to do):

```
@events = Event.all.includes(:prices)
if params.has_key?("price_min") && params["price_min"].length > 0 then
    @events.where("prices.price >= ? AND prices.price IS NOT NULL", params["price_min"])
end
```

This works (but I need that if statement):

```
@events = Event.all.includes(:prices).where("prices.price >= ? AND prices.price IS NOT NULL", params["price_min"])
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `all` is going to execute a `SELECT * from events` when that fires.

You could set it up like this:

```
query = Event.includes(:prices)

if params.has_key?("price_min") && params["price_min"].length > 0 then
    query = query.where("prices.price >= ? AND prices.price IS NOT NULL", params["price_min"])
end

@events = query.all
```

This will dynamically build the query, then execute with the `all` after it is complete.

**Note**: Running this in console won't give you what you expect because the `print` of the REPL will cause the query at each point to execute.

Comment: oh that makes so much sense! just realized that my other parameters had @events = @events.where(...). Seems like it would be a lot more efficient to design it the way you described. Thank you!